# Does an HTTPS SharePoint Site Need to Use HTTPS-Compliant Web Parts?

Tags: sharepoint, https, web-parts

We are planning to create a new sub-site within our company's intranet site, which is built on SharePoint 2007.  We want to add a 3rd-party **weather web part** (which is just a widget to display the local weather forecast) to the home page of the new intranet site.

Since the intranet site uses **HTTPS**, do we need to find an HTTPS-compliant web part? I'm guessing that if we use a non-HTTPS web part, then users will get some sort of "This page contains both secure and non-secure items" error message when they load the page.

**Edit:**

I found this post on SF:  https://serverfault.com/questions/91159/sharepoint-moss-serve-http-content-on-an-https-page-without-mixed-content-warni, which suggests that the most secure option would be to find a 3rd-party weather web part that uses HTTPS (or create one ourselves).  Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the weather is retrieved clientside from a non-https url you'll get an error yes. Providers of feed data should enable https too, did you try if that works? :)

There's a free weather webpart from Bamboo:
http://store.bamboosolutions.com/pc-55-1-world-clock-and-weather-web-part.aspx

The upside is that it retrieves it's feed serverside so you won't have the client-script issue.

The downside is (if I remember well enough, it's been a while) that it attempts to retrieve the weather on every page hit, slowing down the page especially if the connectivity is not there for some reason.

I usually build my own RSS consumers.. with built in caching.